401 Unauthorized error when posting comment after successful login in Node.js application
I am working on a Node.js application where users can register, login, and post comments. User data is stored in a mock file (mockUsers.js) and comments are stored in another mock file (mockComments.js). I am using express-session for session management.
The problem I am facing is that after a user logs in successfully and posts a comment, the comment is saved correctly in the mockComments.js file. However, if the user tries to post another comment, they receive a "401 Unauthorized" error.
Here is the relevant code:
index.js:
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes');
const courseRoutes = require('./routes/courseRoutes');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(session({
  secret: 'your_secret_key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false } // Set to true if using HTTPS
}));

app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/course', courseRoutes);

// Error handling middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

authController.js:
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const users = require('../mocks/mockUsers');

const saveUsersToFile = () => {
  fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../mocks/mockUsers.js'), `const users = ${JSON.stringify(users, null, 2)};\n\nmodule.exports = users;`);
};

const register = (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  if (!username || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Username and password are required' });
  }

  const user = { id: users.length + 1, username, password };
  users.push(user);
  saveUsersToFile();

  res.status(201).json({ message: 'User registered successfully', user });
};

const login = (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const user = users.find(u => u.username === username && u.password === password);

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid credentials' });
  }

  req.session.userId = user.id;
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful' });
};

const logout = (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy();
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Logout successful' });
};

module.exports = { register, login, logout };

courseController.js:
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const comments = require('../mocks/mockComments');

const saveCommentsToFile = () => {
  fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../mocks/mockComments.js'), `const comments = ${JSON.stringify(comments, null, 2)};\n\nmodule.exports = comments;`);
};

const postComment = (req, res) => {
  const { userId, text } = req.body;
  if (!userId || !text) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User ID and text are required' });
  }

  const comment = { userId, text, date: new Date() };
  comments.push(comment);
  saveCommentsToFile();

  res.status(201).json({ message: 'Comment posted successfully', comment });
};

module.exports = { postComment };

authMiddleware.js:
const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.session && req.session.userId) {
    return next();
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
  }
};

module.exports = { isAuthenticated };

courseRoutes.js:
const express = require('express');
const { postComment } = require('../controllers/courseController');
const { isAuthenticated } = require('../middlewares/authMiddleware');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/comment', isAuthenticated, postComment);

module.exports = router;

authRoutes.js:
const express = require('express');
const { register, login, logout } = require('../controllers/authController');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/register', register);
router.post('/login', login);
router.post('/logout', logout);

module.exports = router;

mockUsers.js:
const users = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "testuser",
    "password": "testpassword"
  }
];

module.exports = users;

mockComments.js:
const comments = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "text": "This is a test comment",
    "date": "2024-12-31T16:19:16.107Z"
  }
];

module.exports = comments;

Why am I receiving a "401 Unauthorized" error when trying to post a comment after a successful login? How can I ensure that the session persists and the user remains authenticated for subsequent requests?

Unfortunately, simply asking whether or not a POST request is semantically appropriate for this task is (1) opinion-based and (2) not in any way helpful to the problem you're trying to solve.  Whether we answer with "yes" or "no", even including references to support either opinion, does nothing to address whatever isn't working in your code.
